# How to achieve max 50% height in CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like Top div in the image below to occupy maximum 50% of container's height.

How could I achieve this?

[Playground](http://jsbin.com/vagaferave/1/edit?html,css,output)

[image]

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 30px;
}

.outerContainer {
  margin: 30px 30px 30px 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.container { 
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.top, .bottom {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.top {
  background-color: #aaa;
  max-height: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #bbb;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="title">
      <div>#1</div>
      <div>Short Top</div>
      <div>Short Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top">
        Top Top Top
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        Bottom Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
      Good!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="title">
      <div>#2</div>
      <div>Short Top</div>
      <div>Long Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top">
        Top Top Top
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
      Good!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="title">
      <div>#3</div>
      <div>Long Top</div>
      <div>Short Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top">
        Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top 
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        Bottom Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
      Bad!<br />Top and Bottom should occupy 50% of the height
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="title">
      <div>#4</div>
      <div>Long Top</div>
      <div>Long Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top">
        Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top Top 
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom Bottom 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
      Bad!<br />Top and Bottom should occupy 50% of the height
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your padding on the elements are exceeding the max-height of the divs because of box sizing.

```
body *, * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

this way you're telling the browser what the sizing properties (width and height) should include.